# How does Html.fromHtml works?

Tags: android

My question is very straight forward and related to one the quiet old functionality in Android's HTML class. We all know that  `Html.fromHtml` helps us to deal with HTML content and displays them on `TextView` with ease. Out of curiosity I went into the code and found below code snippet. And now I am wondering that if below code is directly throwing a `RuntimeException`, how this is actually working? Who format the the code ?  Regarding the Deprecated annotation I am quiet clear.

```
/** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public static Spanned fromHtml(String source, int flags) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

Comment: No, you have no access to the source if thats what you see. It's just the IDE doing that.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java

Comment: I don't know from where did you found that code but I found this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/Html.java#Html.fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29 this is real source of that calss. Your one is wrong

Comment: I got the answer from the comments. Someone please close the question who has enough reputation.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi no its ok (no need to delete), unless there are a bunch of downvotes going on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the sources downloaded on your computer.

You can either download the sources, which Android Studio should offer you to do on the upper right corner, when the sources are available, or then look at the sources online.

grepcode.com offers this, but a quick Google for 'Android HTML sourcecode', should give you page containing the source as result.

Here's example of the [Html](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/text/Html.java/?v=source) class that you're looking for in grepcode.